# Цветной текст в IDLE оболочке на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции

Я искал на оригинальном SOF (ссылка внизу статьи), как сделать
  цветным текст в оболочке IDLE. Меня не устраивает, что функцию `color.write(YourText,Color)` долго писать (я собирался позднее часто использовать данную функцию).

Эта часть кода нужна для активации цветного текста:

```
import sys
try: color = sys.stdout.shell
except AttributeError: raise RuntimeError("Use IDLE")
```

И, собственно, цветной текст:

```
color.write('text','hit')
```

Я попробовал упростить её через `def`:

```
def cprint(text, color):
    text = str(text)
    color = str(color)
    color.write(text, color)
    color.write('\n')

cprint("text", 'hit')
```

При выполнении программы выходит AttributeError:

```
  File "C:\...\colortext.py", line 11, in <module>
    cprint("text", 'hit')
  File "C:\...\colortext.py", line 8, in cprint
    color.write(text, color)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'
```

Я пытался решить проблему самостоятельно, попытавшись обмануть Пайтон:

```
def cprint(text, color):
    color.write("%s" %text, "%s" %color)
    color.write('\n')
```

Но ничего не получилось ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Я собирался потом импортировать этот файл как модуль, поэтому команды (по идее) должны быть короткими.

Заранее спасибо!

Ссылки:

Статья оригинального SOF'a - [How do I print colored text in IDLE's terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42472958/how-do-i-print-colored-text-in-idles-terminal)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import sys

def cprint(text, color):
    try:
        shell_stream = sys.stdout.shell
    except AttributeError:
        raise RuntimeError("Use IDLE")
    shell_stream.write(text, color)
    shell_stream.write('\n')

# Тесты:
cprint('Hello, world', 'KEYWORD')
cprint('How are you?', 'STRING')
```

---

Примечания:

1. Не рекомендуют использовать глобальные переменные в определении функций, потому я вложил первую часть вашей программы прямо в неё.
2. Писать `try: color = sys.stdout.shell` (и следующую строку вашей программы) в одной строке противоречит [PEP 8 - руководству по написанию кода на Python](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pep-8-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-koda-na-python.html#id31), потому я написал эти строки как следует.
3. Переменная `color` как параметр вашей функции перекрыла (побила) глобальную переменную с тем же самым именем, так что `color` в теле функции стала обычной строкой — потому возникла ваша ошибка.
   Я использовал имя `shell_stream` для объекта `sys.stdout.shell`.
4. Команды

   ```
   text = str(text)
   color = str(color)
   ```

   я просто пропустил как излишние.

Answer (score 2):

color из sys.stdout.shell не тоже самое, что color - второй аргумент функции.

```
def cprint(text, clr):
    colorText.write(str(text)+'\n', clr)


import sys
try: colorText = sys.stdout.shell
except AttributeError: raise RuntimeError("Use IDLE")

cprint("text", 'hit')
```