# Как вывести цветной тест в консоль на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, текст, вывод

Нужно, чтобы сообщение печаталось зелёным цветом **прямо в консоли**.
Писал код:

```
def out_red(text):
    print("\033[31m {}" .format(text))
def out_yellow(text):
    print("\033[33m {}" .format(text))
def out_blue(text):
    print("\033[34m {}" .format(text))
out_red("Вывод красным цветом")
out_yellow("Текст жёлтого цвета")
out_blue("Синий текст")
```

Но выдаёт вот это:

```
[31m Вывод красным цветом
[33m Текст жёлтого цвета
[34m Синий текст
```

**Помогите, пожалуйста**

Comment: берите https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/how-to-print-colored-text-to-the-terminal

Comment: в вашем случае print("\033[31m" + text)

Comment: попробую сейчас

Comment: @Интик нет, если я хочу сделать текст `ddd` выводит `[31mddd`

Comment: только что проверил text='ddd'
print("\033[31m" + text)  выводид красным ддд.  покажите ваш новый код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ура, нашёл ответ! Вот [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1135953/%D0%A6%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B2-idle-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-python?rq=1)

Вот код:

```
import sys

def cprint(text, color):
    try:
        shell_stream = sys.stdout.shell
    except AttributeError:
        raise RuntimeError("Use IDLE")
    shell_stream.write(text, color)
    shell_stream.write('\n')

# Тесты:
cprint('Hello, world', 'KEYWORD')
cprint('How are you?', 'STRING')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import colorama

colorama.init()

print(colorama.Fore.YELLOW + "Текст")
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]